# How to scrape products data from a website?

Tags: php, curl

I am using `curl_init()` function to scrape products from a website. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$curl_connection = curl_init();
$url = "https://www.registrar.usf.edu/ssearch/search.php";
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');//cookiejar to dump cookie infos.
curl_setopt ($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');//cookie file for further reference from the site
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.registrar.usf.edu/");
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
echo $result;
?>
```

Running this PHP script om Wampserver. But it gives an error i.e.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in D:\wampserver\www\curlurl.php on line 2.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because curl extension is not enabled in your php.ini file. Open your php.ini file and find the line that says:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

And change it to:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Restart your WAMP server and that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ and download the curl version that corresponds to your php version under "Fixed curl extensions:".

So if you have php 5.3.13, download "php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64.zip". Try the "VC" version first. Then replace the php_curl.dll in ext folder. This worked for me.

All credits to: Matthieu Napoli

And... XAMPP is better :)

Comment: @Aashi, please accept/upvote answers if they are useful for you.